# Cancel a sales order

Tags: acumatica

How can a particular sales order be cancelled via code?  Perhaps I can call the ProcessOrders graph, loop through the select orders, and execute the Cancel Order method.  Unfortunately I see no such method.  The drop-down action is driven by the automation menu.  I do not find a cancel order action in the standard sales order entry graph.  So what is the best way to accomplish the goal?

Via code, I can manually set the cancelled flag and status.  This seems to work, but I'm not sure that is recommended.  Seems like I'm skipping something, and the automation menu should be the way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm copying the answer from this Acumatica blog post since it does exactly what you need, call the 'Cancel Order' automation step from code: [Running Automation Step from Code](http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/04/running-automaton-button-from-code.html)

To call automation step you have to:

- Define a new custom PXView that will return record that we want to
  process
- Create an adapter, that will provide data for button handler. Adapter
  will get data from custom PXview.
- Create a separate instance of graph, that will handle action.

**Code:**

```
public class SOOrderEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    //Lets define additional button than will call automation button.    
    public PXAction<SOOrder> ButtonExample;       
    [PXButton()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Button Example")]
    public virtual IEnumerable buttonExample(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        SOOrder order = Base.Document.Current;

        //creating a graph that will process Internal command
        SOOrderEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();

        graph.Document.Current = graph.Document.Search<SOOrder.orderNbr>(order.OrderNbr, order.OrderType);

        //Searching for correct button from that is defined in Automatin steps.
        //All sub  menues are adden under action button, so we can get them and iterate.
        foreach (var action in (graph.action.GetState(null) as PXButtonState).Menus)
        {
            if (action.Command == "Cancel Order")
            {
                //Constructing dummy view that will always return only one record.
                adapter = new PXAdapter(new DummyView(graph, graph.Document.View.BqlSelect, new List<object> { order }));

                //defining a button command
                adapter.Menu = action.Command;

                //running button
                return graph.action.Press(adapter);
            }
        }

        return adapter.Get();
    }

    //Defining a dummy view that is inherited from PXView
    internal class DummyView : PXView
    {
        //Storing list of records
        List<object> _Records;

        internal DummyView(PXGraph graph, BqlCommand command, List<object> records)
            : base(graph, true, command)
        {
            _Records = records;
        }

        //Everytime when system calls select for the view, retun saved records.
        public override List<object> Select(object[] currents, object[] parameters, object[] searches, string[] sortcolumns, bool[] descendings, PXFilterRow[] filters, ref int startRow, int maximumRows, ref int totalRows)
        {
            return _Records;
        }
    }
}
```

I would think it's preferable to call the Automation Step instead of manually setting the **Cancelled** field because if a user changes the Automation Step you would pick up the changes by calling it.

Note that when possible you should always use existing Graph when you need to manually handle data because this will trigger validations.

If you were to manually change the **Cancelled** field using SOOrderEntry instead of calling the automation steps, the following validation in SOOrderEntry would still apply:

```
protected virtual void SOOrder_Cancelled_FieldVerifying(PXCache sender, PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs e)
{
    SOOrder row = (SOOrder) e.Row;
    PXResultset<CCProcTran> trans = PXSelect<CCProcTran, Where<CCProcTran.origRefNbr, Equal<Current<SOOrder.orderNbr>>,
                    And<CCProcTran.origDocType, Equal<Current<SOOrder.orderType>>,
                    And<CCProcTran.refNbr, IsNull,
                    And<CCProcTran.docType, IsNull>>>>>
                    .Select(this);
    CCProcTranHelper.UpdateCCPaymentState(row, trans);
    if (row != null && (row.IsCCAuthorized == true || row.IsCCCaptured == true))
    {
        bool authIsValid = true;
        if (row.IsCCAuthorized == true)
        {
            if (row.CCAuthTranNbr != null)
            {
                CCProcTran authTran = PXSelect<CCProcTran, Where<CCProcTran.tranNbr, Equal<Required<CCProcTran.tranNbr>>>>.Select(this, row.CCAuthTranNbr);
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(authTran.DocType) == false && String.IsNullOrEmpty(authTran.RefNbr) == false)
                {
                    authIsValid = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                CCProcTran authTran = this.ccAuthTrans.Select(); //Double-checking for valid auth tran
                if (authTran == null)
                    authIsValid = false;
            }

            if (authIsValid && row.CCAuthExpirationDate.HasValue)
            {
                authIsValid = row.CCAuthExpirationDate.Value > PXTimeZoneInfo.Now;
            }
        }
        if (authIsValid)
        {
            sender.RaiseExceptionHandling<SOOrder.cCPaymentStateDescr>(row, row.CCPaymentStateDescr, new PXSetPropertyException(Messages.CannotCancelCCProcessed, PXErrorLevel.Error));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of method action.GetState(null) ?  Each time that line is executed, the dreaded error happens:  "object reference not set to an instance of an object".  I have seen this approach before and used successfully in conjunction with SOShipmentEntry.  SOOrderEntry results in an error.  Also I checked to see that my SOOrderEntry graph has an order assigned to the cache.  Thank you HB

Comment: The purpose is to get a reference to the Menu Items collection that contains the Cancel Order action, action variable is a reference to the menu root folder. I'm a bit short on time to test it atm, can you debug it to see which Type this is returning 'graph.action.GetState(null)' ? I would guess it's different than the expected 'PXButtonState' now. Otherwise debug to see if 'graph' or 'action' is null, I would be surprise if that's the case though.

Comment: If the null reference error happens inside the GetState method you should see that in the traces (Help->Traces), please add those traces to your question if possible.